# Find the Domain and Sketch The Graph of The Function $g(x) = \frac{3x+|x|}{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Do I take the x out of the absolute value sign?

If so $ \frac{x(3+1)}{x} = 3+1$, thus, $4$

Which would only be a point. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3):

You have made a couple of errors. First, you can't just factor $x$ out and cancel it. If $x<0$, then you would get $x(3-1)$, not $x(3+1)$, since $|x| = -x$ for $x<0$. Next, even if you could, to get $\frac{x(3+1)}{x}$, this is defined only for $x\ne 0$.

Yes, where it is defined, the resulting function would be $4$, but this is not a point: rather, for each nonzero value of $x$, the function returns $4$, so that its graph would be the line $y=4$ except at $x=0$, where it would be undefined. (I must point out again that this calculation is incorrect, since you can't simply factor out the $x$; I'm writing all of this so that you can understand what other pitfalls you have to deal with).

To do this properly, the simplest method is probably to write the given function as *two* functions, one of which is valid for $x<0$ and the other for $x>0$ (note again that $x=0$ is not in the domain of the function).